# What is a variable's linkage and storage specifier?

Tags: c++, c

When someone talks about a variables storage class specifier, what are they talking about?
They also often talk about variable linkage in the same context, what is that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The storage class specifier controls the *storage* and the *linkage* of your variables. These are two concepts that are different.
C specifies the following specifiers for variables: auto, extern, register, static.

**Storage**
The storage duration determines how long your variable will live in ram.
There are three types of storage duration: static, automatic and dynamic.

*static*
If your variable is declared at file scope, or with an extern or static specifier, it will have static storage. The variable will exist for as long as the program is executing. No execution time is spent to create these variables.

*automatic*
If the variable is declared in a function, but **without** the extern or static specifier, it has automatic storage. The variable will exist only while you are executing the function.  Once you return, the variable no longer exist.  Automatic storage is typically done on the stack.  It is a very fast operation to create these variables (simply increment the stack pointer by the size).

*dynamic*
If you use malloc (or new in C++) you are using dynamic storage.  This storage will exist until you call free (or delete). This is the most expensive way to create storage, as the system must manage allocation and deallocation dynamically.

**Linkage**
Linkage specifies who can see and reference the variable. There are three types of linkage: internal linkage, external linkage and no linkage.

*no linkage*
This variable is only visible where it was declared. Typically applies to variables declared in a function.

*internal linkage*
This variable will be visible to all the functions within the file (called a [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160/multiple-classes-in-a-header-file-vs-a-single-header-file-per-class)), but other files will not know it exists.

*external linkage*
The variable will be visible to other translation units.  These are often thought of as "global variables".

Here is a table describing the storage and linkage characteristics based on the specifiers

```
  Storage Class   Function            File 
  Specifier        Scope              Scope  
-----------------------------------------------------
  none           automatic         static      
                 no linkage        external linkage

 extern          static            static
                 external linkage  external linkage

 static          static            static
                 no linkage        internal linkage

  auto           automatic         invalid
                 no linkage

register         automatic         invalid
                 no linkage
```

Comment: Should perhaps include an extra bit of detail on translation units as they aren't just files... they are source files plus any headers included in them (however indirectly)

Comment: Wow... +1. Note that "auto" will change its meaning with C++0x : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x

Comment: Update for c++11: thread storage duration. The object is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of the object. Only objects declared thread_local have this storage duration. thread_local can appear together with static or extern to adjust linkage.

Answer (score 0):

Variable storage classes or type specifiers (like volatile, auto and static) define how/where variables are saved during program execution. For example, variables defined in functions are usually saved on the stack, which means that it will be lost after the function returns. Using the "static" keyword, you can force the compiler to put the variable in the data segment in memory, making the variables content persistent between calls to that function. The "register" keyword will cause the compiler to try as hard as possible to put the variable in a CPU register, useful for counters in loops etc. However, it's not guaranteed that it's actually in a register after all.

Read more about type specifiers [here](http://www.space.unibe.ch/comp_doc/c_manual/C/CONCEPT/storage_class.html).

Comment: For an odd definition of "try as hard as possible" which usually means "do nothing at all". `register` is completely obsolete except to document (by enforcement) that your code is not allowed to take the address of a variable.