# Linkage of formal parameters

Tags: c

I have a function say foo defined as

```
void foo (int foo_arg)
{
  printf("%d",foo_arg);
}
```

What is the linkage type of foo_arg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C there  are three kinds of linkage: external, internal, and none.

Formal parameters have *no linkage*

Section `6.2.2/6` (ISO C99)

> The following identiﬁers have no linkage:
>
> - an identiﬁer declared to be anything other than
>   an object or a function;
> - **an identiﬁer declared to be a function parameter**;
> - a block scope
>   identiﬁer for an object declared without the storage-class speciﬁer extern.

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95890/what-is-a-variables-linkage-and-storage-specifier) thread.