# local structure and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have a function which takes a structure as a parameter, like:

```
add_new_structure(structure s);
```

then store it inside 
`structure structure_list[200];`

question:

**1.** when I want to use the structure, I have a function like

```
structure *getStructure(int id)
{
return &structure_list[id];
}
```

is it gonna work if I add one structure like this:

```
void init()
{
   structure test;
   memset(&test,0,sizeof(structure));
   add_new_structure(test);
}
```

and then call getStructure from another function? like this:

```
void anotherFunction()
{
    structure *got_test = getStructure(0);
}
```

because I remember  I can't have local variable and then call it from another function right?

**2.is it better to just store it like this?**

change the `add_new_structure() parameter to structure *s`;

then store it inside 
`structure *structure_list[200];` by calling add_new_structure(&test);

**3. which one is better? or what is the right way to do it?**

Comment: Does `structure_list` have static storage duration? You might want to post the definition of `add_new_structure()` and the `struct`. If the `struct` has any pointers then just copying them can be dangerous.

Comment: yes it has a long list of  structure members,contain char pointers,so how to store them in array safely? what is static storage duration?

Comment: static storage duration means lasts for the lifetime of the program (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95890/what-is-a-variables-linkage-and-storage-specifier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach, i.e. you pass the instance directly as a parameter, works. Because the whole instance is copied when calling the function. And what you store is a copy of the original struct instance.

However, you can't pass and store a pointer to a local variable. The problem you mentioned above will occur in this case.

IMHO, neither of the above approaches are right. The first approach will introduce too much overhead when passing parameters to the function. While the second one cannot achieve what you want.
You'd better dynamically allocate memory with `malloc`/`calloc` and store the pointer in the array. Don't forget to release the object at the end of use in case of memory leak. Like this:

```
void init()
{
   structure *test = NULL;
   test = (structure *) calloc(1, sizeof(structure));
   add_new_structure(test);
}

void add_new_structure(structure *s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 2, as I think you point out, will not work. It's a bit more subtle than saying that pointers to local variables can't be used outside of a function; it's that they are only valid while the function is still "active", so to speak. In option 2, a pointer to `structure test` would be stored inside of `structure *structure_list[200]` when you call `add_new_structure`. At this point, some function is calling `init` which is calling `add_new_structure`. When you return from `init`, the memory address you put into `structure_list` is no longer owned by the original owner, and this is dangerous. If this is too mechanical of an explanation, you should look at how stacks work to see why.

Without using `malloc` and its friends, which can introduce a lot of complexity, I would be inclined to keep the memory stored in `structure_list`, with the minor modification that you can pass `structure test` by reference and not by value. This is probably a reasonable compromise between the two stylistically.

```
void init() {
    structure test;
    memset(&test,0,sizeof(structure));
    add_new_structure(&test);
}

void add_new_structure(structure *s) {
    if (structure_count < 200) {
        structure_list[structure_count++] = *s;
    }
}
```

A lot of this depends on what `structure` is (if it contains pointers itself, who owns those?), but hopefully this provides some intuition.