# How good is this representation of a context free grammar for a parser?

Tags: c++, parsing

i have shared the header file containing class definition of a Context Free grammar for a parser. Could you comment on the design.
this code is for my lab assignment.
may be we could get some good programming tips out of this code. is the class hierarchy good or too complicated.

```
#ifndef CFG_H
#define CFG_H

#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <list>

using namespace std;



class Terminal;


class CfgSymbol
{
protected:
    char ch;
    set<Terminal*> first;
    set<Terminal*> follow;

public:
    CfgSymbol()
    {
        ch = '\0';
    }

    CfgSymbol(char c) : ch(c)
    {
    }

    virtual void computeFirst() = 0;
};


class Terminal: public CfgSymbol
{
private:

public:
    Terminal(): CfgSymbol()
    {
    }

    Terminal(char c) : CfgSymbol(c)
    {
        computeFirst();
    }

    virtual void computeFirst()
    {
        first->insert(this);
    }

};

class NonTerminal: public CfgSymbol
{
private:

public:
    virtual void computeFirst();
    virtual void computeFollow();
};

class SymbolString
{
public:
    CfgProduction* prd;
    list<CfgSymbol*> symstr;

    void computeFirst();
    void computeFollow();
};

class CfgProduction
{
private:
    NonTerminal lhs;
    SymbolString rhs;
public:
    int add_terminal(char t);
    int add_nonterminal(char n);
    int set_lhs(char c);
};

class Cfg
{
public:
    vector<CfgProduction*> prdList;

    void addProduction(const CfgProduction& cfg);
    void computeFirst();
    void computeFollow();
    void computeFirstFollow();

};

#endif
```

Comment: somebody please correct the code tags.

Comment: You need to indent entire code with 4 spaces (and not tabs). BTW, putting implementation in header is a bad idea, unless it's necessary (i.e. templates). And putting `using namespace` in a header is IMHO always a bad idea.

Comment: ok but what about the class heirarchy of a context free grammar.

Comment: does this look like a composite design pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spirit's documentation](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/distrib/spirit_1_8_5/libs/spirit/index.html) should give you a nice intro for [grammar](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/distrib/spirit_1_8_5/libs/spirit/doc/grammar.html) implementation (with templates). Don't know your level, maybe that's too simple, but its quite interesting :

> As a grammar becomes complicated, it
>   is a good idea to group parts into
>   logical modules. For instance, when
>   writing a language, it might be wise
>   to put expressions and statements into
>   separate grammar capsules. The grammar
>   takes advantage of the encapsulation
>   properties of C++ classes. The
>   declarative nature of classes makes it
>   a perfect fit for the definition of
>   grammars. Since the grammar is nothing
>   more than a class declaration, we can
>   conveniently publish it in header
>   files. The idea is that once written
>   and fully tested, a grammar can be
>   reused in many contexts. We now have
>   the notion of grammar libraries.

Comment: great got to learn something new

Answer (score 2):

Without comments the whole things is meaningless.

There should be some lengthy description about how an object instance is used and in what context it is used.

On the other hand I normally start with a BNF Grammar definition ( at leas in the comments) before the class definition. Then design the classes around the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

You should not write implementations in the header except for templates. Header must contains only signatures of your class and functions, and your members.

Convention will be to put only one class per file. It's better for compilation : [Multiple classes in a header file vs. a single header file per class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160/multiple-classes-in-a-header-file-vs-a-single-header-file-per-class).
But I think it is correct to put many classes in the same header if classes are less than 10 lines long.

Comment: For one, since it doesn't answer the question, I think this would have belonged to a comment.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to group classes (or not) in a file according to their length. IMO several classes belong into the same header if either `A)` they are a complete set of related and rather small classes or `B)` one of them is the main class and the others are a complete set of rather small helpers and satellites.

Comment: I agree with you. In my mind regrouping small classes included your conditions.