# "X does not name a type" error in C++

Tags: c++, windows, types

I have two classes declared as below:

```
class User
{
public:
  MyMessageBox dataMsgBox;
};

class MyMessageBox
{
public:
  void sendMessage(Message *msg, User *recvr);
  Message receiveMessage();
  vector<Message> *dataMessageList;
};
```

When I try to compile it using gcc, it gives the following error:

> MyMessageBox does not name a type

Comment: The endless times I go this error, just to realize that the import guards generated by the IDE are duplicated

Comment: Note that you can also get this error if you place an extern reference to a declaration in a .h / .hpp file before the class is defined, even when you have the actual declaration after the .h / .hpp inclusion within the .cpp file.

Comment: You should also always compile C++ files with command `g++` and not `gcc`

Answer (score 256, accepted):

When the compiler compiles the class `User` and gets to the `MyMessageBox` line, `MyMessageBox` has not yet been defined. The compiler has no idea `MyMessageBox` exists, so cannot understand the meaning of your class member.

You need to make sure `MyMessageBox` is defined *before* you use it as a member. This is solved by reversing the definition order. However, you have a cyclic dependency: if you move `MyMessageBox` above `User`, then in the definition of `MyMessageBox` the name `User` won't be defined!

What you can do is *forward declare* `User`; that is, declare it but don't define it. During compilation, a type that is declared but not defined is called an *incomplete type*.
Consider the simpler example:

```
struct foo; // foo is *declared* to be a struct, but that struct is not yet defined

struct bar
{
    // this is okay, it's just a pointer;
    // we can point to something without knowing how that something is defined
    foo* fp; 

    // likewise, we can form a reference to it
    void some_func(foo& fr);

    // but this would be an error, as before, because it requires a definition
    /* foo fooMember; */
};

struct foo // okay, now define foo!
{
    int fooInt;
    double fooDouble;
};

void bar::some_func(foo& fr)
{
    // now that foo is defined, we can read that reference:
    fr.fooInt = 111605;
    fr.foDouble = 123.456;
}
```

By forward declaring `User`, `MyMessageBox` can still form a pointer or reference to it:

```
class User; // let the compiler know such a class will be defined

class MyMessageBox
{
public:
    // this is ok, no definitions needed yet for User (or Message)
    void sendMessage(Message *msg, User *recvr); 

    Message receiveMessage();
    vector<Message>* dataMessageList;
};

class User
{
public:
    // also ok, since it's now defined
    MyMessageBox dataMsgBox;
};
```

You *cannot* do this the other way around: as mentioned, a class member needs to have a definition. (The reason is that the compiler needs to know how much memory `User` takes up, and to know that it needs to know the size of its members.) If you were to say:

```
class MyMessageBox;

class User
{
public:
    // size not available! it's an incomplete type
    MyMessageBox dataMsgBox;
};
```

It wouldn't work, since it doesn't know the size yet.

---

On a side note, this function:

```
 void sendMessage(Message *msg, User *recvr);
```

Probably shouldn't take either of those by pointer. You can't send a message without a message, nor can you send a message without a user to send it to. And both of those situations are expressible by passing null as an argument to either parameter (null is a perfectly valid pointer value!)

Rather, use a reference (possibly const):

```
 void sendMessage(const Message& msg, User& recvr);
```

Comment: +1 Learned something today - I thought forward declaring `MyMessageBox` would've been enough. What if `MyMessageBox` had a variable of type `User` too - would that be a deadlock?

Comment: @Amargosh: Yes, it would be impossible. Logically impossible as well, since `User` would have a `MessageBox` which would have a `User`, which would have a `MessageBox` which would have a `User`, which would have a `MessageBox` which would have a `User`, which would have a `MessageBox` which would have a `User`...

Answer (score 12):

1. Forward declare User
2. Put the declaration of MyMessageBox before User

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it turned out that this very uninformative error was caused by a circular dependency. Instead of

```cpp
// A.hpp
#include "B.hpp"

class A {
    B b;
}

// B.hpp
#include "A.hpp"

class B {
    A a;
}
```

I changed the second file to

```
// B.hpp
class A;

class B {
    A a;
}
```

... and all the compiler errors, as well as the sudden lack of syntax highlighting in my IDE, disappeared.

I did need to later put a `#include "A.hpp"` at the top of the `B.cpp` file, but that's fine, because there's no circular dependency in that case (`B.cpp -> A.hpp -> B.hpp -> /`).

Comment: This was my issue. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

C++ compilers process their input once. Each class you use must have been defined first. You use `MyMessageBox` before you define it. In this case, you can simply swap the two class definitions.

Comment: Swapping won't work as `MyMessageBox` has `User` type in it's method declaration.

Comment: Actually, that definition doesn't _use_ class `User`. Important distinction, because that means class User only needs to be _declared_ at that point, not _defined_. But see GMan's extensive post.

Comment: Yeah, but simply swapping the definitions won't work as `User` type is not declared yet.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define MyMessageBox before User -- because User include object of MyMessageBox *by value* (and so compiler should know its size).

Also you'll need to *forward declare* User befor MyMessageBox -- because MyMessageBox include member of User* type.

Answer (score 3):

On a related note, if you had:

```
    class User; // let the compiler know such a class will be defined

    class MyMessageBox
    {
    public:
        User* myUser;
    };

    class User
    {
    public:
        // also ok, since it's now defined
        MyMessageBox dataMsgBox;
    };
```

Then that would also work, because the User is defined in MyMessageBox as a pointer

Comment: Forward declaration is the term

Answer (score 2):

You must declare the prototype it before using it:

```
class User;

class MyMessageBox
{
public:
 void sendMessage(Message *msg, User *recvr);
 Message receiveMessage();
 vector<Message> *dataMessageList;
};

class User
{
public:
 MyMessageBox dataMsgBox;
};
```

**edit**: Swapped the types

Comment: No, won't work. Class members must be defined, not forqward declared.

Answer (score 1):

It is always encouraged in C++ that you have one class per header file, see this discussion in SO [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160/multiple-classes-in-a-header-file-vs-a-single-header-file-per-class)].
GManNickG answer's tells why this happen. But the best way to solve this is to put `User` class in one header file (`User.h`) and `MyMessageBox` class in another header file (`MyMessageBox.h`). Then in your `User.h` you include `MyMessageBox.h` and in `MyMessageBox.h` you include `User.h`. Do not forget "include gaurds" [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards)] so that your code compiles successfully.