# structure does not name a type in c++

Tags: c++, struct, compilation

I get an issue while return type is structure

```
Example.h

class Example {
private:
    typedef struct connection_header {
        string url;
        string method;
    };

    static connection_header get_connection_header();
};

Example.cpp
connection_header Example::get_connection_header() {
    return NULL;
}
```

I am getting `'connection_header' does not name a type`

may i know why is this error

Comment: Your next error will probably be `no conversion from int to connection_header`. What type is `NULL`?

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks for the notification i was from java so we usually can do that.and i fixed that issu

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["X does not name a type" error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/x-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c) and [Class name does not name a type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3608305/608639)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are using `typedef` without giving a name to the type. Just drop the `typedef`, it is not needed here:

```
struct connection_header {
    string url;
    string method;
};
```

Next, `connection_header` is declared inside of the `Example` class, so you need to fully qualify its name in the implementation when it is a return type:

```
Example::connection_header Example::get_connection_header()
```

Comment: I don't think this is good advise in C++, you'll want structs to behave like classes, without the need to type the `struct` keyword in front of the object name all over the plac.

Comment: @Lundin it is not all over the place. This is the actual declaration of the `struct`.

Comment: But when you use the struct you have to type `struct connection_header` since connection_header is not a type, but a struct tag.

Comment: @Lundin no, `connection_header` is a type. This is how you declare structs and classes in C++.

Comment: @Lundin, no, you are wrong. These days, a struct is just a class with different default accessibility rules.

Comment: @TonyK Fair enough then, but is there a reason why you would write code that isn't backwards-compatible, when you can get that compatibility for free, with no effort?

Comment: @Lundin then you wouldn't really be able to use C++. Yes, you can write a subset of C in C++ and compile it as both, but that is extremely limiting.

Comment: @downvoter Any reason for the downvote, given that the answer is correct?

Comment: @Lundin Using a C-style declaration for a `struct` *inside a `class`* is not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 3):

First, in C++ (but not C) every `struct` or `class` names a type. So if you declare a `struct connection_header`, you also get a `connection_header` type, so you can later declare `connection_header var` some variable.

Then, `typedef` both in C and C++ needs a type and a name. For example:

```
 typedef long my_number_type;
```

declares `my_number_type` as a synonym for `long`

So as others pointed out, drop the `typedef`

Answer (score 3):

Try below code in `cpp` file, add `Example::` before `connection_header` :

```
Example::connection_header Example::get_connection_header() {
    return NULL;
}
```

`connection_header` is defined inside `Example` so you should give it its definition scope.

Also, the keyword `typedef` will be ignored in C++. You can omit it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers of others, I recommend that you do not nest the definition of your data structures. Create a separate external `struct` for `connection_header` above the `Example` `class`.

```
Example.h

struct ConnectionHeader {
    string url;
    string method;
};

class Example {
private:
    ConnectionHeader connection_header;
    static ConnectionHeader get_connection_header();
};
```

This is much simpler to debug, offers better reusability, and makes it easier to predict the results of `auto`. Otherwise, just make `url` and `method` members of `Example` and have `get_connection_header()` update these values in-place, returning `void`.

Answer (score 0):

There another typical problem, which is that you used a type that is has not yet been declared. If you use types, declare them before using them.