# "Y does not name a type" error in C++

Tags: c++, class, struct, variable-assignment

I don't know what to search to find an explanation for this, so I am asking.
I have this code which reports error:

```
struct Settings{
    int width;
    int height;
} settings;

settings.width = 800; // 'settings' does not name a type error
settings.height = 600; // 'settings' does not name a type error

int main(){
    cout << settings.width << " " << settings.height << endl;
```

but if I put the value assignment in main, it works:

```
struct Settings{
    int width;
    int height;
} settings;

main () {
    settings.width = 800; // no error
    settings.height = 600; // no error
```

Can you explain me why?

**EDIT:**
Regarding to Ralph Tandetzky's answer, here is my full struct code. Could you show me how to assign the values as you did with my snippet struct?

```
struct Settings{
    struct Dimensions{
        int width;
        int height;
    } screen;

    struct Build_menu:Dimensions{
        int border_width;
    } build_menu;
} settings;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["X does not name a type" error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/x-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c) and [Class name does not name a type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3608305/608639)

Comment: @jww While your point is correct, I like the [Andy's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938810/y-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c/#16938849) the most because of its _simplicty_. Also thumbs up for the funny title changes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot put assignments outside the context of a function in C++. If you're puzzled by the fact that you sometimes saw the `=` symbol being used outside the context of a function, such as:

```
int x = 42; // <== THIS IS NOT AN ASSIGNMENT!

int main()
{
    // ...
}
```

That's because the `=` symbol can be used for *initialization* as well. In your example, you are not initializing the data members `width` and `height`, you are assigning a value to them.

Comment: wow such a subtle issue. had never noticed.+1. only thing missing here is the usual std reference. are you andy or some other guy who hacked into andy's account?:-)

Comment: Oh damn, awesome. I am using initialization too, so I wasn't understanding why this didn't work since I had several more variables before this struct.  

So to be clear. `int i = 5;` would work, but `int i;` followed by `i = 5;` wouldn't work?

Comment: @AndyProwl could you provide some insight on this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938810/does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c/16938991?noredirect=1#comment24455731_16938991). basically on the "extending the struct".

Comment: @Koushik: That's a question that would probably call for a separate answer - I am not sure I understand the OP's design, and I do not have time to think too much about it now ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl ah fair enough now leaving you to complete your grand design :-)

Answer (score 9):

In C++11 you can write

```
struct Settings {
    int width;
    int height;
} settings = { 800, 600 };
```

in order to fix your bug. The error appears because you're trying to assign a value outside a function body. You can initialize but not assign global data outside of a function.

**EDIT:**

Concerning your edit, just write

```
Settings settings = {{800, 600}, {10, 20, 3}};
```

I'm not 100% sure, if this works though, because of the inheritance. I would recommend to avoid inheritance in this case and write the `Dimensions` as member data into your `Build_menu` structure. Inheritance will sooner or later give you all kinds of trouble, when used this way. [Prefer composition to inheritance.](http://books.google.de/books?id=mmjVIC6WolgC&pg=PT218&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) When you do that, it's gonna look like

```
Settings settings = {{800, 600}, {{10, 20}, 3}};
```

Comment: can write this too `struct Settings {
    int width = 10;
    int height = 20;
} settings;`

Comment: Oh thanks, regarding this, I would have another question. The struct I posted was just a snippet of my real struct. I will update my question, would you be so kind and see how could I make it work using this assignmenet? I am defining my struct at the begin of my main.cpp (after includes of course) so it is the first thing to see in my code. That's why I would prefer such value assignmenet, instead of in main() which is on 300th line.

Comment: @Qwerty this is just the initialization. thses set your struct to some initial value so that you know the state of these members. afterwards you can change it accoringly in the program.\

Comment: @Koushik I edited the question so you can see my full struct code. Since I am extending a struct within a struct, how would I assign values as you proposed? Also I don't like much the struct Build_menu build_menu thing. Is there a way to just extend build_menu with one more option and not to create a struct for it?

Comment: @Qwerty assign as i showed its simple but only works in c++11 mode. Ralph's method also can be applied but you have to have brace within brace initialization. as far as build_menu thing is concerned if you want to "extend" it no other option. also it depends on you design.

Comment: *"In C++11 you can write"* - Can't you even do that in C++98, given that `Settings` should be an aggregate type?

Comment: @Koushik I broke the the inheritance and now I have `struct Screen{ int w=800; int h=600; } screen;` and `struct Menu{ int w=600; int h=400; int s=20; } menu;`. Everything is inicialized and neatly categorized.

Comment: @Qwerty yes i cannot say much about your design s. but if this solves your problem them i'm glad. remember this is only in c++11. Ralph's method applies to c++ 98/03 as well(as long as it is just a plain old struct) as ChristianRau noted.

Comment: Vote up for the summary, **You can initialize but not assign global data outside of a function.**, precisely pointing out the error here. Here is [why can't I assign for global variables outside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661263/why-cant-i-assign-values-to-global-variables-outside-a-function-in-c)