# Error C++ : does not name a type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a ploblem with the next code, I get the error: 'ptab' does not name a type and 'pfreeC' does not name a type, I don't understand how to solve that, thanks for your help =)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std; 
int *ptab;                     //Here is the error
ptab=new int[64]; 

bool *pfreeC;             //Here is the error
pfreeC=new bool[11];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938810/does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have code outside a function body

```
using namespace std; 

int *ptab;                     
bool *pfreeC;  

int main()
{
   ptab = new int[64];
   pfreeC = new bool[11];
   return 0;
}
```

Of course you should also delete the allocated memory. Or even better, use smart pointers.

Comment: Thank you, I saw a lot of examples before, but I didn't understand,,,,,