# What happens in initialization in C++

Tags: c++

Why can I do

```
int x;

int main(){
    cout << x;
}
```

and it returns 0.

But when I do

```
int x;
x = 5;

int main(){
    cout << x;
}
```

I get an error?

edit: Turns out if I move all that inside my main() I can run it fine but I don't know why I can't put this initialization and assignment outside my main()?

Comment: you can, write `int x = 5;` outside `main`

Comment: Statements (e.g. `x = 5;`) cannot appear outside of a function. Declarations and definitions can, though. Note that `int x;` is only a declaration and does not give `x` a value, unless it is of static lifetime.

Comment: Oh, that's weird it was returning 0 for me so I assumed it just automatically assigned x = 0 upon initialization, is that not the case? @iz_

Comment: I know I can do that but why can't I just do what I did outside main as well? @user3365922

Comment: And why can't I have a statement outside of a function?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `int x;` will initialize `x` with `0` if `x` is static or global (like in this case). However, if you move `int x;` inside a function, it will not be given a value. In C/C++, the compiler executes code with an instruction pointer. If code is not organized into functions, the code will never run.

Comment: *And why can't I have a statement outside of a function?* Thems the rules. I suspect this is done for organizational purposes, for example, when would this code be run? Would it be before or after similar global statements in other files? Sorta related: an integer with static storage duration will be initialized to zero if not specifically initialized. This is not true of an integer that is automatically allocated in a function.

Comment: can you comment what error you are getting?

Comment: Different language but in this case also answering the question for C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661263/why-cant-i-assign-values-to-global-variables-outside-a-function-in-c/50661315

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I assign values to global variables outside a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661263/why-cant-i-assign-values-to-global-variables-outside-a-function-in-c)