# Cannot access Arduino struct fields. ERROR "exit status 1. xxxx does not name a type"

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, arduino, typedef

I cannot make the Arduino IDE compile when using structs. I define a simple struct called `params` to hold my parameters.

When I try to access the fields of the struct `params` using the "." it throws this error

```
exit status 1
'params' does not name a type
```

I already searched and tried many different things. I tried putting definitions into a separate .h file and tried putting my sketch into a .cpp file instead of using .ino, but I cannot make this struct work!

I am pretty sure the syntax is correct and it shall work in C++. I don't get while Arduino IDE gives me this error!

Here is the code from the top of my .ino file. If you can help me it would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <MIDI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

// address for Terabee laser sensor connnected via USB
#define ADDRESS 0x55

const int num_sensors = 3;

typedef struct {    // holds all free parameters (for presets)
  int test;
  int reverse[num_sensors];
  int active[num_sensors];
  int sensor_range[num_sensors];
  int cc_num[num_sensors];
  int channel[num_sensors];
  int default_value[num_sensors];  // for rubber-band mode
  int min_value[num_sensors];
  int max_value[num_sensors];
} parameters;



// Created and binds the MIDI interface to the default hardware Serial port
MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();


parameters params;
params.test= 2;   // COMPILER THROWS ERROR ON THIS LINE!!!!!!!!!
//params.cc_num = {22, 23, 24};
//params.reverse = {false, false, false};
//params.sensor_range = {150, 150, 150}; //upper limit (how far shall the hand go?)
//params.default_value = {64, 64, 64};  // rubber-band defaults for the 3 sensors
//params.min_value = {0, 0, 0};
//params.max_value = {127, 127, 127};

void setup() {   [....]
```

I am using global variables, I don't know if it's a good idea, but I am new to Arduino and for now it was working fine, only adding structs creates all the problems.

Also, just defining the struct with `parameters params;` compiles. The error arises when trying to access the fields, like `params.test = 2;`

Comment: "*I am pretty sure the syntax is correct and it shall work in C++.*" [It doesn't.](https://ideone.com/sTnDR5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Y does not name a type" error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938810/y-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code in a function and call it:

```
void test() {
    params.test= 2;  
    params.cc_num = {22, 23, 24};
    params.reverse = {false, false, false};
    params.sensor_range = {150, 150, 150}; 
    params.default_value = {64, 64, 64};  
    params.min_value = {0, 0, 0};
    params.max_value = {127, 127, 127};
}
```

In c and c++ pre c++11 you cannot initialize non static member as global vars.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Arduino, but the following code:

```
params.test= 2;
```

... and all the other (currently commented out) lines that assign values to members of the structure, *ought to be inside a function*. Perhaps the Setup() function you've defined below?

I think that previously you would have been able to compile statements such as:

```
int test = 2;
```

... because in this case the '=' operator is *initializing* the value of a variable, rather than *assigning* a value to a structure member