# c++ struct does not name a type error

Tags: c++

I get the following errors when trying to compile this code, why?

"game.h:48:42: error: ‘player’ does not name a type

game.h:48:50: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘enemies’ with no type [-fpermissive] "

Line 48 is the function "fillMap" btw

```
//game.h

#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

//CONSTANTS AND TEMPLATES

const int LEN = 40;

struct player
{
   char name[LEN]; //name of character
   char symbol; //character representing player on map
   int posx; // x position on map
   int posy; // y position on map
   bool alive; // Is the player alive
   double damage; // Player attacking power
   double health; // Player health
};

enum direction {LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};

//PROTOTYPES

//move amount specified in position structure
void moveAmount(player& pl, int posx, int posy);

//move to specified position on map
void moveTo(player& pl, int posx, int posy);

//one player attacking other
//returns whether attack was successfull
bool attack(const player & atacker, player & target);

//one player attacking a direction on the map, epl is a pointer to an array of enemies           players
//returns whether attack was sucessfull
bool attack(const player & pl, direction, player* epl);

//Check if player is dead, to be called inside attack function
inline bool isDead(const player& pl){
    return pl.health <= 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

//Remove player from map if he is dead
void kill(player& pl);

//Initialize map
void fillMap(const player& player, const player* enemies, int mapWidth, int mapHeigth);

//Display map
void displayMap(const int mapWidth, const int mapHeigth);

#endif
```

Comment: Your variable has the same name (`player`) as the type...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["X does not name a type" error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/x-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c) and [Class name does not name a type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3608305/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
void fillMap(const player& player, const player* enemies, int mapWidth, int mapHeigth);
```

Since you declare `player` as a parameter, it remains in scope for the entire forward declaration. Therefore, its name shadows the type name `player`: inside the forward declaration of `fillMap`, `player` refers to the first parameter, not to the `player` type.

Rename it to `pl` to fix this problem:

```
void fillMap(const player& pl, const player* enemies, int mapWidth, int mapHeigth);
```

Comment: Oh..That simple than...Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Because `player` isn't a type; `struct player` is.

Comment: Sure `player` is the name of a type. But that name is hidden by a variable name.