# Class does not name a type C++ compilation error

Tags: c++, header

I know this questions have been answered so many times on stackoverflow and I have been searching through them yet still cant be solved yet. The problem in this case might due to something called circular dependencies and I have tried some solutions mentioned in another post like forward declaration or put in header guard but still not working. And I have no idea why this error occurs to only the ItemComponent file while the rest all working fine.

Edit: It occurs while compiling the InputController.hpp file, line 13 with the error : "error: 'ItemComponent' does not name a type; did you mean 'TileComponent'?"

Here are the files and Im using c++17 with premake5:

ItemComponent.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include "Components.hpp"
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "../Game.hpp"
#include "../TextureManager.hpp"
#include <map>

class ItemComponent : public Component
{
public:
    int box;
    int tWidth, tHeight;
    int width , height;
    int scale;

    struct ToolInfo
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        SDL_Texture* tex;
    };
    
    std::map<int, ToolInfo> ToolMap;
    std::map<std::string, int> ItemMap;
    SDL_Rect bracket[2], src, dest;
    SDL_Texture *tex;

    int text_width;
    int text_height;
    SDL_Surface *surface;
    SDL_Texture *textTex;
    SDL_Rect textRect;
    SDL_Color textColor = {27, 27, 27, 160};
    TTF_Font *font;
    std::string text = "Unequipped";
    SpriteComponent* sprite;

    ItemComponent()
    {
        // Toolbox pos 
        tWidth = 64;
        tHeight = 64;
        box = 2;
        scale = 3;

        // Tool render initialization
        width = height = 16;
        tex = TextureManager::LoadTexture("game/assets/Objects/Items/tools and meterials.png");
        ToolInfo hoe = { x: width*2, y: height*0, tex: tex};
        ToolInfo axe = { x: width*1, y: height*0, tex: tex};
        ToolMap.emplace(1, hoe);
        ToolMap.emplace(2, axe);
        ItemMap.emplace("Hoe", 1);
        ItemMap.emplace("Axe", 2);

        // Text
        font = TTF_OpenFont("game/assets/Font/UniversCondensed.ttf", 20);
    }
    ~ItemComponent() {};

    void RenderToolbox();
    void RenderText();
    void RenderUpdateToolbox(std::string item);
    void UpdateText(std::string newText);

    void init() override
    {
        // Toolbox pos
        for (int i = 0; i < box; i++)
        {
            bracket[i].x = tWidth * (i+1) + (i * 10);
            bracket[i].y = 25;
            bracket[i].w = tWidth;
            bracket[i].h = tHeight;
        }
        sprite = &entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>();
    }

    void draw() override
    {
        RenderText();
        RenderToolbox();
        if (sprite->action.onHold)
        { RenderUpdateToolbox(sprite->action.name); }

        for (int i = 0; i < box; i++)
        {
            src.x = ToolMap[i+1].x;
            src.y = ToolMap[i+1].y;
            src.w = width;
            src.h = height;
            tex = ToolMap[i+1].tex;

        dest.x = bracket[i].x + 10;
        dest.y = bracket[i].y + 10;
        dest.w = width * scale;
        dest.h = height * scale;
        TextureManager::Draw(tex, src, dest, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
    }
}

private:
};

#endif // TOOLCOMPONENT_HPP
```

InputController.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include "Components.hpp"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "../Game.hpp"
class InputController : public Component
{
public:
    TransformComponent *transform;
    SpriteComponent *sprite;
    ItemComponent *item; // Error occurred here ****

    InputController() = default;
    ~InputController() {}

    void init() override
    {
        item = &entity->getComponent<ItemComponent>();
        transform = &entity->getComponent<TransformComponent>();
        sprite = &entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>();
    }
    // Codes....
    void update() override;
    void draw() override;
};
```

Compnents.hpp (include all the header)

```
#pragma once

#include "ECS.hpp"
#include "TransformComponent.hpp"
#include "SpriteComponent.hpp"
#include "ItemComponent.hpp"
#include "InputController.hpp"
#include "ColliderComponent.hpp"
#include "TileComponent.hpp"
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error to your question, and which line is failing

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes sure, already edited.

Comment: Difficult to tell without a [mre] but getting rid of `Compnents.hpp` and just including the headers you need directly will likely fix your issues

Comment: InputController.hpp does not include ItemComponent.hpp or have a forward declaration.

Comment: Circular includes via `Components.hpp`

Comment: When you have circular dependencies between header files, it may be you have a design issue. Make (pure virtual) baseclasses for your classes (and derive your classes from them) put them in seperate header files and use those. Look for articles on "dependency inversion"

Comment: Header guards have nothing to do with cyclic inclusion. You **have** to break the cycle. That might mean forward declarations, it might mean a redesign of your classes. Here's a tip, it's slow but it will work. Delete all your headers, put all your header file code into one huge header file. You cannot get cyclic includes if you only have one header file. Get your code to compile using that one header file. Then **slowly** start to migrate code from that huge header file into separate header files, making sure that it still compiles at every step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class name does not name a type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608305/class-name-does-not-name-a-type-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be able to fix the issue by

1. Avoiding an "include all" (`Components.hpp`), but instead just including what you need.
2. Working with forward declarations as long as possible, even delaying the `#include` directives until ***after*** the definition of the class. This can help avoid the scenario where an included header requires the definition of the class in the current header to be complete.

The following code should work given the info in the question. Note that lacking the info about where `Component` is defined, I'm using `Comp.hpp` for this. Also I ignore any members of types you don't define.

**ItemComponent.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Comp.hpp" // parent class required at class definition

class SpriteComponent; // full type definition not needed for the body of the class

class ItemComponent : public Component
{
public:
    ...
    SpriteComponent* sprite;

    ItemComponent()
    {
        ...
    }
    ~ItemComponent() {};

    void RenderToolbox();
    void RenderText();
    void RenderUpdateToolbox(std::string item);
    void UpdateText(std::string newText);

    void init() override;

    void draw() override;
}

private:
};

#include "SpriteComponent.hpp" // required for the definitions of draw and init

inline void ItemComponent::init()
{
    ...
    sprite = &entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>();
}

inline void ItemComponent::draw()
{
    ...
    if (sprite->action.onHold)
    { RenderUpdateToolbox(sprite->action.name); }
    ...
}
```

**InputController.hpp**

```
#include "Comp.hpp"

// pointers in the class body don't require the following types to be complete:
class ItemComponent;
class SpriteComponent;
class TransformComponent;

class InputController : public Component
{
public:
    TransformComponent *transform;
    SpriteComponent *sprite;
    ItemComponent *item;

    InputController() = default;
    ~InputController() {}

    void init() override;
    // Codes....
    void update() override;
    void draw() override;
};


// include definitions required in init
#include "ItemComponent.hpp"
#include "TransformComponent.hpp"
#include "SpriteComponent.hpp"

inline void InputController::init()
{
    item = &entity->getComponent<ItemComponent>();
    transform = &entity->getComponent<TransformComponent>();
    sprite = &entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>();
}
```

You may want to go with a translation unit corresponding to every header though and implement all member functions there; in this case except for the parent class definition forward declarations would be sufficient and you could `#include` at your leisure in your `.cpp` files without risking circular includes, since your `.cpp` files aren't included in other files.

Comment: Personally I'd rather see `InputController::init` moved to a source file rather than having header files included part way through another header file.