# ... undefined reference to ... collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, linker, ld, undefined-reference

I have the following 3 files:

error.h

```
#ifndef error_h
#define error_h
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
void Error(std::string msg);
#endif
```

error.cpp

```
#ifdef error_h
#include "error.h"
void Error(std::string msg)
{
    std::cerr
     << "\n=========================================================\n"
     << msg
     << "\n=========================================================\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
#endif
```

foobar.cpp

```
#include "error.h"
int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<99; i++)
        if(i==55)
            Error("this works");
    return 0;
}
```

Now I do:

```
$ g++ -c error.cpp foobar.cpp
$ g++ error.o foobar.o -o exampleprogram
```

And I get:

```
foobar.o: In function `main':
foobar.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `Error(std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to understand to resolve this, and similar issues in the future without asking questions? Thanks!

Comment: now I also realize that exit(int) is in cstdlib and not in cstdio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you have these lines in *error.cpp*?

```
#ifdef error_h
  ...
#endif
```

Since the preprocessor symbol `error_h` is not defined the entire contents of *error.cpp* are being omitted by the preprocessor. Remove those lines and your program will link successfully.

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how (and maybe why) `#include` guards are to be used. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020211/241631) answer for an explanation.

Also, there's no need to include *iostream* and *cstdio* in *error.h*, since that file is not using anything declared in either of those headers. Those files should be included in *error.cpp*.

Comment: Thank you! I have been doing a lot of ".cpp including" of template implementations lately and I just typed these without thinking and overlooked them the whole time. You mentioned iostream and cstdio includes... does this mean that I have to scatter around some of the includes? Some in the .h and some in the .cpp? Is #include <string> needed by the function prototype? Isn't there a way of bundleing all the includes for a .h and .cpp in general? Thanks again.

Comment: @user1358 Best practice is to only include the headers that are actually needed in that file, so yes, includes tend to be scattered around. There's nothing incorrect about including both the headers in *error.h*, but when you include *error.h* in *main.cpp*, the preprocessor will include the files in the translation unit created from *main.cpp* and the compiler will have to process those headers as well. Not really a concern in small projects, but for large projects this can significantly impact build times.

Comment: Your explanations helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this

```
#ifdef error_h
```

and the corresponding `#endif` from `error.cpp`. Otherwise, here:

> $ g++ -c error.cpp foobar.cpp

`error.cpp` is essentially empty. This is because at that stage `error_h` is not defined. So you are not compiling the implementation (it would work if you had included `error.h` *before* the `#ifdef`, but there is no reason to have that in the `.cpp` file anyway).

Answer (score 2):

`error_h` is not defined in error.cpp, so all your file content gets #ifdef'd away.

In essence, you're compiling error.cpp as an empty file.