# multiple definition in stl class header

Tags: c++, stl, linker

I am getting stuck using this class, when I used in the main.cpp there is no problem and execute perfectly, but when I use it as a member class the compiler doesn't like it and sends the message "Multiple definition of:"
Here is the class:

RTPSocket.h:

```
#ifndef RTP_SOCKET_HDR
#define RTP_SOCKET_HDR
    namespace RTPConnection
    {

    enum EMode
    {
        Sender,
        Receiver
    };

    template<EMode Mode>
    class RTPSocket
    {
    };
    }//end namespace


#define RTP_SOCKET_IMP
#include "RTPSocket_Imp.h"//file where i declare the implementation code
#undef RTP_SOCKET_IMP
#endif
```

this class by itself doesn't have any problem but when i use it in my class, but ....
used in another class
my file.h

```
#include RTPSocket.h 
class CommClass
{
private:
RTPSocket<RTPConnection::Receiver>  * mRTPServer;
}
```

the compiler give this error message:
multiple definition of 'enum RTPConnection::EMode'

this is a method that is declared in another file "rtpsocket_imp.h"
with the guard declared:

```
template<EMode Mode>
void RTPSocket<Mode>::write(char* aArray, 
                                      const size_t aiSize)
{
    std::string message("The write function is operative only on Sender Mode");
    throw BadTemplate(message);
}
```

Comment: Do you have include guards in your real code?

Comment: yes, but i didnt mention i the post, my fault

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong with code we can't see.

Comment: this is a function thar i wrote:

Comment: template<EMode Mode>
void RTPSocket<Mode>::write(char* aArray, 
                                      const size_t aiSize)
{
    std::string message("The write function is operative only on Sender Mode");
    throw BadTemplate(message);
}            this method was writting was declared in rtpsocke_imp.h and the guard have been included

Answer (score 4):

You want include guards around the header:

```
#ifndef RTPSOCKET_H
#define RTPSOCKET_H

// header contents go here

#endif
```

This will prevent the header contents from being included more than once per source file, so you will not accidentally get multiple definitions.

**UPDATE**: Since you say you have include guards, then possible causes of the error might be:

- misspelling the include guard name, so it doesn't work
- defining something with the same name in another header (or the source file that includes it)
- undefining the include guard name.

But without seeing code that reproduces the error, I can only guess what might be wrong.

Comment: sorry i didnt mentiod in the original post, but the guard are included

Comment: @Ricardo_arg: Then please post some code (including the guards) that actually reproduces the error; we can only guess what's wrong with the code you don't show us.

Answer (score 3):

You need an [include guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards).
Inside the RTPSocket.h  file at the top put

```
#ifndef RTPSOCKET_INCLUDED
#define RTPSOCKET_INCLUDED
```

and at the end put

```
#endif
```

If that's not the problem, and you do have an include guard, I suggest you search for

> enum EMode

in your code and find all the places you have defined it, and make sure you just define it once.

Comment: Guard are included, sorry i didnt put in the original post

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the CMakeLists.txt that was building this project. 
My fault!