# Access a member variable of a sister object in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to access a variable which is inside of an object (TestClassThree.h) which is inside the parent class (TestClassOne.h). Each class is in its own file, and when I try to import the files to instantiate the classes it crashes. I suspect it is because of import loops. I don't think that I can use forward class declarations, because that would restrict the access to the variable. How can I access the variable inside of TestClassThree from TestClassTwo?

```
//--TestClassOne.h--
#include "TestClassTwo.h"
#include "TestClassThree.h"

class TestClassOne {
public:
    TestClassTwo *myVariable;
    TestClassThree *mySecondVariable;

    TestClassOne() {
        myVariable = new TestClassTwo(this);
        mySecondVariable = new TestClassThree();
    }
};

//--TestClassTwo.h--
#include "TestClassOne.h" //<-- ERROR

class TestClassTwo {
public:
    TestClassOne *parent;

    TestClassTwo(TestClassOne *_parent) : parent(_parent) {

    }

    void setValue() {
        parent->mySecondVariable->mySecondVariable->value = 10;
    }

};
```

Comment: Presumably when you say "crashes" you really mean "I get a compiler error message"?

Comment: I don't think you can include a.h in b.h and b.h in a.h simultaneously. It will lead to infinite depth dependence.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `forward class declarations` and `friend` Keyword

Comment: I dont think he needs friend since all class members are public

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a so-called include guard (cf. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards)). In `TestClassOne.h` add the following lines at the top and bottom of the file:

```
#ifndef TESTCLASSONE_H
#define TESTCLASSONE_H

[...]

#endif
```

Add this also to `TestClassTwo.h`, but change the name of the preprocessor macro to TESTCLASSTWO_H.

Answer (score 0):

Both what said herzbube and patato answered your question :

1 - Avoid "includes loops" using #ifndef / #define macros just like herzbube explained

2 - Use forward classes declarations to tell the compiler a class will be defined after

```
// 1- avoid "include loops"
#ifndef TESTCLASSONE_H
#define TESTCLASSONE_H

// 2- Forward classes declarations
class TestClassTwo;
class TestClassThree; // assuming TestClassThree needs TestClassOne.h

class TestClassOne{
...
};
#endif
```