# error C2011: '' : 'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2005

One of the header files is as follows -

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class AAA
{
public:
    std::string strX;
    std::string strY;
};
```

When I try to compile the project, I get the error

```
error C2011: 'AAA' : 'class' type redefinition
```

Nowhere else in my program have I redefined the class `AAA`. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to use include guards.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Change to code to something like this:

```
#ifndef AAA_HEADER
#define AAA_HEADER

#include "stdafx.h"

class AAA
{
public:
    std::string strX;
    std::string strY;
};

#endif
```

If you include this header file more than once in some source file, include guards will force compiler to generate class only once so it will not give `class redefinition` error.

Comment: Is AAA_HEADER the AAA.h file?

Comment: AAA_HEADER is just unique string to identify the file. Read about include guards here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that it will work for all C++ compilers, not just Microsoft's.

Answer (score 37):

Adding

```
#pragma once
```

to the top of your AAA.h file should take care of the problem.

like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once

class AAA
{
public:
    std::string strX;
    std::string strY;
};
```

Comment: Should it be more likely at the very top of the file (at first line) not after some includes?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the suggested include guards you need to move #include "stdafx.h" out of the header. Put it at the top of the cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem today in VS 2017. I added `#pragma once`, but it didn't work until I added a macro definition:

```
    // does not work    
    #pragma once
        
    // works with or without #pragma once
    #ifndef _HEADER_AAA
    #define _HEADER_AAA
    //
    // my code here....
    //
    #endif
```

I have no clue how to explain this, but it is a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this but you can't use both. Make sure to wrap the class definition with a compiler directive that the class declaration only gets compiled once:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#pragma once

class AAA{
public:
    std::string strX;
    std::string strY;
};
```

-or-

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
    
    #ifndef AAA_HEADER_
    #define AAA_HEADER_
    
    class AAA
    {
    public:
    
        std::string strX;
        std::string strY;
    
    };
    
    #endif
```

Also: note the class import statement should be at the top of your file.