# error C2011 and defined

Tags: c++

I have search for error 2011 I found [error C2011: '' : 'class' type redefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713718/error-c2011-class-type-redefinition), and I definitely got #ifndef and #define in my c++ code.

Here is my code

```
//Member.h
#ifndef MEMBER_H
#define MEMBER_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class member
{
private:
    int id;
    string name;
    char sex;
    int age;
public:
    void addMember();
    void setName(string n);
    void setSex(char s);
    void setAge(int a);
};
#endif
```

.

```
//Member.cpp
#include <string>
#include "Member.h"
using namespace std;

class member
{
private:
    int id;
    string name;
    char sex;
    int age;
public:
    void addMember()
    {
        void setName(string n);
        void setSex(char s);
        void setAge(int a);
        //relationship
    }
    void setName(string n) { name = n; }
    void setSex(char s) { sex = s; }
    void setAge(int a) { age = a; }
};
```

It gives me the same error C2011. Please help

Comment: Probably there is another class member defined somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have other custom headers that precede the include of this one in one of your .cpp files? Maybe you have forgotten the `;` at the end of another class, forgott a closing `}` or the `#endif`. That are the usual causes for these kind of errors, because `class` is a keyword and not a type, so somewhere there must be syntax error before.

Comment: By the way, a using directive in a header is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clearly defined the class `member` twice- once in the header file and once in the C++ file, exactly like the compiler told you was the problem.