# Class redefinition error with multiple #include files? (C++)

Tags: c++, header, include

Basically this:

Car and Truck are both derived from the Vehicle class.

Car.h

```
#include "Vehicle.h"
class Car : public Vehicle {
//blah blah blah
```

Truck.h

```
 #include "Vehicle.h"
 class Truck : public Vehicle {
 //blah blah blah
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"
#include "Truck.h"
```

My issue is that I get a class redefinition error on Truck (due to it calling Vehicle a second time) when I have the #include line there, but when I remove it, I have the "expected class name before { token".

I get that with 
Main -> Car -> Vehicle
Main -> Truck -> Vehicle (redefinition)

will cause an error.

But if I remove the #include "Vehicle.h" from Truck it also causes another error where it expects a class name.

Comment: Try to use #ifndef or #pragma once

Comment: You need header include guard in all your header files. This link contains more detals on include guard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Answer (score 6):

As @ErikW pointed out you need to use include guards. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards).

### Example

### Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H // This needs to be unique in each header
#define FOO_H

... code goes in here ...

#endif
```

Comment: I still get errors when using include guard though. With include guard it says "expected class name before { token"

Comment: @user3551329 Perhaps you could show more of your code (e.g., Vehicle.h), maybe you have a circular include issue. You'll get the best help if you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: my Vehicle header file has no includes in it. And my Vehicle.cpp file has only an #include Vehicle.h. I'll try to reproduce it.