# C++ Class redefinition error - I cannot figure this out for the life in me

Tags: c++

Any help on why I am getting a `'C2011 'Transaction':'class' type redefinition`? I'm sure it's glaringly obvious but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Please help.

**transaction.h**

```
#include <string>

class Transaction
{
private:
    int amount;
    std::string type;

public:
    Transaction(int amt, std::string kind);
    std::string Report();
};
```

**transaction.cpp**

```
#include "transaction.h"

using namespace std;

Transaction::Transaction(int amt, std::string kind):amount(amt), type(kind)
{
}

string Transaction::Report()
{
    string report;
    report += "  ";
    report += type;
    report += " ";
    report += to_string(amount);

    return report;
}
```

Comment: What's inside `transaction.h`?

Comment: It's at the top of the question, after //transaction.h

Comment: You need an [include guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards) in transaction.h.

Comment: You will have to forgive me Mohamad, I am relatively new to this; what is a header guard and how would I implement it?

Comment: Try `#pragma once` at the top of the header file to see if it works for you.

Comment: You absolute beauty, thank you for the help Linus, that works fine!

Comment: @ArronTaylor Great, glad I could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use a header guard in the header file which will make sure you never ever more than once define a class or struct etc. in any other cpp file.

To add a header guard you can simply do this:

```
#ifndef TRANSACTION_H
#define TRANSACTION_H
// your header file
#endif
```

Or simply add

```
#pragma once
```

to all your header files and you're good.

Comment: Thanks for the help Linus; much appreciated.

Comment: Didn't see that you gave the answer in the comments first. Upvote for giving the two possibilities

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **include guards** in `transaction.h`:

```
#if !defined(your_symbol)
#define your_symbol 1
/*ToDo - code here*/
#endif
```

Where, `your_symbol` is typically an embellishment of the name of the file. Be careful not to use a leading double underscore or a single leading underscore followed by a capital letter as they are reserved symbols.

This prevents the class declaration from being included more than once in any compilation unit.

You can use `#ifndef your_symbol` in place of my first line, and drop the 1 from the second line, or perhaps even just use a `#pragma once` directive at the top of the file, but the version I present works on every compiler I've ever come across.

Answer (score 0):

In your header try this:

```
#ifndef TRANSACTION  //If transaction has never been defined before
#define TRANSACTION  //Define transaction
//Content of your header
#endif
```

This  header guard will probably help you. Indeed it will prevent your header from being included multiple times which leads to redefinitions. If you include your header just once you don't need these guards, but it doesn't hurt to have them anyway.

Alternatively, you can use `#pragma once` at the beginning of your header.

If you want to read more about them, check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)