# Error when separating function into another source file in C

Tags: c++

I have a simple project:

method.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef _METHOD_
#define _METHOD_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int plus(int a, int b);

#endif // _METHOD_
```

method.cpp:

```
#include "method.h"

int plus(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Source.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include "method.h"

void main()
{
    int a = plus(4, 5);
    printf("%d",a);

    printf("\n");
    _getch();
}
```

but when I build project, an error occure:
[image]

I'm a newbie in C programming.
And so sorry about my grammar mistakes

Comment: remove #ifdef _METHOD_
#define _METHOD_ as #pragma once does the same and if you want to use guards it should be #ifndef ....

Comment: can you explain for me about remove #ifdef METHOD #define METHOD

Comment: oh i'm sorry, #ifndef instead of #ifdef

Answer (score 3):

remove

```
#ifdef METHOD 
#define METHOD
```

as `#pragma once` does the same and if you want to use guards it should be

```
#ifndef ....
```

`#ifdef _METHOD_` will ignore the header file as you are never defining "`_METHOD_`"

## Update #1

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4141z1cx.aspx) on `#pragma once`;

> Specifies that the file will be included (opened) **only once** by the
> compiler when compiling a source code file.

Comment: oh, sorry, ifndef instead of ifdef. Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: @TrầnHồngPhát Useful reading on what's going on there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard . `#pragma once` is a type of include guard that is not covered by the standard so not all compilers support it. In fact, that's what `#pragma` means. When you see a `#pragma`, make sure your compiler supports it because if it does not, the compiler is allowed to silently ignore it and much debugging may ensue. [Be warned of a few problems with `#pragma once`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34884735/4581301) that block standardization.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change "#ifdef *METHOD*" in your header file to "#ifndef *METHOD*"