# Stack.h:13:3: error: ‘Cell’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, stack

I have a problem with next code, i get the following error

> Stack.h:13:3: error: ‘Cell’ does not name a type

I don't understand how to solve that, thanks for your help.

```
// in a stack, we are in interested in its top value only. The default constructor initializes the stack to
// be empty
class Stack {
    public:
        Stack();
        void push(int value); // push adds a value at the top of the stack 
        int top(); // returns the top value
        void pop(); // removes the top value
        int size() const;  // size returns the number of values in the stack 
        bool empty() const; // returns true if the stack is empty
        int getNext() const;
    private:
        Cell *m_firstCellPtr; // m_firstCellPtr field is a pointer to the first cell of the linked list holding the values of the stack 
        int m_size; // fields holds the current size of the stack

};
```

Every example i have got of the book C++17 By Example By Stefan Björnander
February 2018

Comment: Did you include the header for `Cell`? If you did make sure the header for `Cell` does not include the header for `Stack`

Comment: Lots of possible reasons for this. Could we have a [mcve]?

Comment: Would i include the header _Cell.h_ for _Stack_?

Comment: You could do that, but in general it's best to forward-declare types that are used as pointers or references in another header.  _i.e._ just declare `class Cell;` somewhere before your `Stack` definition.  In `Stack.cpp` you would still include `Cell.h`

Comment: I include _Cell.h_ in _Stack.cpp_, but i have the same error. Too declare _class Cell_ in another header.

Comment: The first three lines of code in that book doesn't look too promising. `using namespace std; void main() { srand( ...`

Comment: ***that book doesn't look too promising*** It currently has a 2 out of 5 rating on Amazon but only 5 total reviews.

Comment: I get too error with this book. Only the first examples to compile.

Comment: `I include Cell.h in Stack.cpp` but your error is in Stack.h, include Cell.h in Stack.h.

Comment: Compilers are very stupid. The compiler is reading Stack.h from begining to end and if at the point you starting talking about `Cell` the compiler hasn't seen a declaration of `Cell` its going to complain. It doesn't look around for a definition somewhere else, you have to include the definition yourself, in this case by #including Cell.h in Stack.h.

Comment: You could also do #2 in the current answer and leave the `#include "Cell.h"` alone in  `Stack.cpp`

Comment: @john include _Cell.h_ in _Stack.h_. I get this: error: redefinition of ‘class Cell’

Comment: @MuxMux Well need to see some real code then, can't debug this without it.

Comment: @MuxMux Probably your header files are missing *include guards*, do you know about those? I notice Stack.h above doesn't have any include guards, but maybe you didn't bother to post that part of the header file.

Comment: @john hi John. https://github.com/Villelmo/Stack

Comment: @MuxMux Yes as I thought, no include guards. You should write headers on the assumption that they may be included several times in a single compilation. Include guards are the answer to this issue. They're very easy, here's a slightly long winded explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line `Cell *m_firstCellPtr;` refers to a type `Cell` which is obviously not known at that point.

This is very likely because the book just shows the `Stack`-portions on this page without mentioning that you will have to declare `Cell`, e.g. by including something like a `#include "Cell.h"`

Three ways to get out of this:

1. `#include "Cell.h"`, if the book's ressources provide it
2. forward declare `Cell` as `class Cell;` before the definition of `Stack`;
3. change the line to `class Cell *m_firstCellPtr;`