# Class not being recognized by second class in another hpp

Tags: c++, oop

In this project composed of a main and 2 clases Point2D and Edge, the Point Class is not being recognized as a type in the Edge.hpp file

file Point2D.hpp

```
class Point2D
{
    float x;
    float y;
 public:
     Point2D(float,float);
    ~Point2D();
}
```

file Point2D.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point2D.hpp"
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

Point2D::Point2D(float xx, float yy)
{
    x=xx;
    y=yy;
}
```

file Edge.hpp

```
class Edge
{
    Point2D pA;
    Point2D pB;
public:
    Edge(Point2D,Point2D);
    ~Edge();
};
```

file Edge.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Edge.hpp"
#include <math.h>

Edge::Edge(Point2D paa, Point2D pbb){
     pA.setx(paa.getx())
     pA.sety(paa.getx())
     pB.setx(pbb.getx())
     pA.sety(pbb.getx())

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "Point2D.hpp"
#include "Edge.hpp"
using namespace std;

....
```

The error I am seeing:

[image]

[image]

I bet it has something to do with the #include headers on each of the files, maybe I am missing something or something is wrong with them... any idea? what should I include at the top of each file?

Besides, if I add

```
#include "Point2D.hpp"
```

in the Edge.hpp file I get the error:
C:...\Point2D.hpp|1|error: redefinition of 'class Point2D'

Comment: You need to `#include "Point2D.hpp"` in `Edge.hpp`. You also likely want to add [include guards](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8020113) to your headers.

Comment: I already tried that, but then I get this error: C:...\Point2D.hpp|1|error: redefinition of 'class Point2D'|.  So I thought I shouldn't

Comment: You need include guards too.

Comment: @ChrisMM what is that? sorry, I am a newbie

Comment: There's a link in my comment. I respectfully submit you might wish to consider following it.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, thanks for the link, just a couple of doubts from what I read 1) I must not add guards in the main.cpp , right?, and 2) Should I add guards in the cpp and hpp files for standard libraries like #include <iostream> and <math.h>. For example, I am using the <iostream>  in main.cpp, Point2D.cpp and Edge.cpp, not adding it would result in a triple inclusion, wouldn't it?

Comment: They are called "include guards" because you use them in files that you `#include`. No, you shouldn't modify files that are part of the standard library - if they need include guards, they'd already have them. Set them up in the files you write.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I noticed that the guards are only put in hpp files. Putting them in cpp files leads to errors. The question is why?   Since cpp files always contain a #include "<class_name>.hpp",  it seems like putting guards there should be necessary too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Igor points out, you need to `#include "Point2D.hpp"` in `Edge.hpp`:

```
#include "Point2D.hpp"

class Edge
{
    Point2D pA;
    Point2D pB;
public:
    Edge(Point2D,Point2D);
    ~Edge();
};
```

so the compiler knows what a `Point2D` is.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler already know what a Point2D is from its inclusion in the main.cpp file? Isn' it redundant?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: You need to understand what a "translation unit" is. Usually, each .cpp file is compiled individually to object code, which is then *linked* together. I.e., each .cpp file needs to make any necessary `#include`s.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: You need better introduction material. This is very, very basic, and inherited from C...