# How Header files and macros are related?

Tags: c, header, macros, c-preprocessor

just a beginner question, what's going on with `#ifndef SOME_HEADER_H` understandable that it is a preprocessor directive for conditional compilation, if some header is already included (i might be wrong correct me?) move on , if it's not,  `include` it, i read at some blog the letter sentence with these words instead, if it's defined move on else `#define` it, well i thought we can just include a header file not define a header file , how can a header file be defined, and what's the relation here ? and the second question, the file name was `foo.h` and when he try to check if it's defined he does `#ifndef FOO_H #define FOO_H`, ok how `foo.h` have been translated to `FOO_H` , does the c mechanism know that he's talking about that specific file or does he done something before-word? thank's for your time!

Comment: Very roughly `#include` is insertion, and macros are search-and-replace.

Comment: clear, how a header file can be treated as a macro?

Comment: Because it is *easier* to place the header guard test in the header itself. Not only does the coder of the including file not have to worry about remembering to do it conditionally, they don't have to look up the exact name of the identifier.

Comment: And for your second question (please, one question per question) then that's a normal [header include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). There's no relation between the header file name and the macro being defined. You could define a macro name `FOOBAR` for a header file name `hoppla.h`.

Comment: A header is not treated as a macro. The header defines a macro when first included and checks for existancs of the macro when included again. The fact that the macro name and the name of the header are similar is just because you chose it to be similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ #include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as translating `foo.h` as `FOO_H`, nor such thing as "defining that a .h has already been included". Using preprocessor variables is just the standard way C developers ensure that .h are not included twice.

In C preprocessor, you can use things such as `#if`, `#else` and `#endif` in order to make logic. You can also `#define` variables, to store information. You can also use the function `defined(...)` to check if a C-preprocessor variable is already defined. The `#ifdef MY_VARIABLE` directive is just a shorthand for `#if defined(MY_VARIABLE)`, and `#ifndef` is just the opposite of that.

On the other hand, you don't want a .h to be included twice, there are several ways to do this, but the standard way is:

```
/* Check if my variable has already been declared */
#ifndef MY_aWeSoMe_VARIBLE

/* If we are in here, it mean that it is not */
/* So let's declare it */
#define MY_aWeSoMe_VARIBLE

/* You can write some more code here, like your .h stuff */

/* And of course, it's time to close the if */
#endif  /* This closes the MY_aWeSoMe_VARIABLE ifndef */
```

The 1st time your complier will include the `.h`, `MY_aWeSoMe_VARIABLE` won't be defined yet, so preprocessor will get inside the `if`, define the variable, include all the `.h`'s code. If your compiler comes to include the `.h` a 2nd or more time, the variable will already be defined, so the preprocessor won't get inside the `if`. Since all the `.h`'s content is inside the `if`, it won't do anything.

Since naming a variable `MY_aWeSoMe_VARIABLE` is pretty stupid, people tend to name it like `MY_FILE_NAME`, or `MY_FILE_NAME_H`, but this is not mandatory, practices actually vary from one dev to another.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a *header guard*:

File: **`some_header.h`**

```
#ifndef SOME_HEADER_H  // if SOME_HEADER_H is not defined, enter the
                       // #ifndef ... #endif block
#define SOME_HEADER_H  // and define SOME_HEADER_H

struct foo {
    int x;
};

#endif
```

This protects the header from being included more than once in the same translation unit and thereby trying to define the same entities more than once. The macro `SOME_HEADER_H` will stay defined until the translation unit is done so no matter how many times this header is included in the translation unit (implicitly via other header files) its contents will only be parsed once for that translation unit.

You can now do this:

File: **`some_other_header.h`**

```
#ifndef SOME_OTHER_HEADER_H
#define SOME_OTHER_HEADER_H

#include "some_header.h" // this header uses some_header.h

struct bar {
    struct foo x;
};

#endif
```

And a program can now include both header files without getting an error like `redefinition of 'foo'`.

File: **`main.cpp`**

```
#include "some_header.h"
#include "some_other_header.h"

int main() {}
```

A non-standard but quite popular alternative to the classic header guards shown above is `#pragma once` which does the same thing (if your preprocessor supports it):

File: **`some_header.h`**

```
#pragma once
// no need for a named macro or #endif

struct foo { ... };
```

Comment: if i can see, for a foo.h the header guard is written the in the foo.h it self . so when we call it in other files, we make sure it's not included more than once ?

Comment: @Question The header guard in the header file itself yes. I added a little example