# Avoiding multiple includes c++

Tags: c++, include-guards

My header files are structured as follows

```
                  base.h
                 /      \
                /        \
       utilities.h       parameters.h
               \           /
                \         /
                 kernels.h
```

Where  `utilities.h` consists only of functions and `parameters.h` consists of class and function templates alongside their type specified definitions i.e.

```
// In parameters.h

// Function templates
template<typename T>
T transform_fxn(const T& value, std::string& method) { T a; return a; }
template<>
int transform_fxn(const int& value, std::string& method){
    .....   
}
template<>
double transform_fxn(const double& value, std::string& method){
    .....
}


// Class templates
template<typename T>
class BaseParameter {
    .....
}

template <typename T>
class Parameter;

template<>
class Parameter<double> : public BaseParameter<double> {
    .....
}
template<>
class Parameter<int> : public BaseParameter<int> {
    .....
}
```

The `kernels.h` file requires both templates in parameters and functions in `utilities.h`, however both are dependent on `base.h`. How do I avoid importing `base.h` in either `utilities.h` or `parameters.h`? Rather, whats an efficient way to import?

Comment: You tagged this `circular-dependency` but I don't see a circular dependency anywhere here. Are you looking for [include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards/8020211)?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Double inclusion is usually not a problem, since it's prevented by include guards.

Comment: Thanks couldnt find the write terms for this issue. include guards are the one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be not possible to avoid include headers several times, because you need usualy to include headers which are needed by the source code. But you can use include guards. There are two kinds of it:

```
#ifndef BASE_H
  #define BASE_H

... <your code>

#endif
```

or another method is the following:

```
#pragma once
```

Both are helpfull to avoid problems.

Answer (score 3):

cross platform you do include guards like this.

parameters.h

```
#ifndef PARAMETERS_H
#define PARAMETERS_H

... your header stuff here ...

#endif
```

MSVC (and most other compilers) also allow for

```
#pragma once
```

at the top of the header. And it will also insure the header is only included once.

Comment: Literally every modern compiler supports `#pragma once`, not only MSVC.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for that feedback. (Part of me mostly living in an MSVC world)

Comment: Consider incorporating this into your answer.