# How to use a class function in C++?

Tags: c++, class, friend

I obtain a `error: 'func' does not name a type` when a member function `func` of a class `B` attempts to return a class `C`:

```
class A {
    public:
        class B {
            public:
                C func() const {
                    ...
                }
            private:
                friend class A;
        }

        class C {
            public:
                ...
            private:
                friend class A;
        }
    private:
        ...
}
```

Whereas, if `func` is a member function of A, then the following does not produce this error:

```
class A {
    public:
        class B {
            public:
                ...
            private:
                friend class A;
        }

        C func() const {
            ...
        }

        class C {
            public:
                ...
            private:
                friend class A;
        }
    private:
        ...
}
```

How can I fix it to make the first version work?

I found a great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c).

Comment: Why are you declaring classes inside another class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define class C "above" class B, or forward declare it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint on forward declaring!

Comment: Im still curious why you can get away without a forward declaration in the second example...