# error: does not name a type, when setting pointer to class to 0

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying get the hang of basics of C++, and I am stuck on this piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace::std;

class Node
{
public:
  int x;
  Node *ptr_next;

};

class LinkedList
{
public:
  Node *head;
  head = 0; //If I comment out this line the code compiles
};

int main()
{
  LinkedList linked_list;
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the above I get this error:

```
error: ‘head’ does not name a type
```

I don't understand why I can't set `head` to `0`; I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c) and it seemed that a possible cause for the above error is compiler not knowing what referenced class (in my case `Node` is). However, this should not be the case here because if I just declare `head` to be a pointer to `Node` my code runs fine. It's when I try to set `head` to `0` the above error is raised. What am I missing?

If I ignore the `LinkedList` class, and change `main` to:

```
int main()
{
  Node *head;
  head = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine. So it is some interaction between `Node` and `LinkedList` that I am missing. What is it?

Comment: Use a NSDMI or constructor.

Comment: You can't write code to initialize stuff (unless something like a const int is used) in a class declaration, use a constructor to do it

Comment: Thank you both, adding constructor to `LinkedList` classed fixed the problem.

Comment: @Marco A to be specific, you can't statically initialize non-integral types. That's actually not why the error is thrown though. The OP is, as written, redefining the ``LinkedList::head`` variable and doing so without giving it a type specifier.

Comment: @aruisdante, can you explain in little more detail why the error is thrown? Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @MarcoA. [Yes you can.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f3af073d4e7613e) Need C++11 though and put it right at declaration.

Comment: That's right, I was assuming pre-C++11 since there's no tag. +1

Comment: I was using C++11; I added the tag.

Comment: Statements can appear only inside function definitions, not in class definitions. Since the compiler isn't expecting a statement at that point, it tries (and fails) to parse `head = 0;` as a declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 allows in class initialization of non-static data members; this is referred to as a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in the standard. The initializer must appear in the declaration of the data member. But you're trying to initialize it in a separate statement. Change the code to

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
  Node *head = nullptr; // don't use 0 to initialize pointers
};
```

And, as the name *brace-or-equal-initializer* alludes to, the initialization can also be done using a *braced-init-list*. So the following works too

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
  Node *head{};  // value-initializes the pointer
};
```