# C++ Class inside of other class with pointer to first class

Tags: c++

I want to build a "game engine" / state manager for my game and I have a c++ specific problem now.

I have a class gameEngine.

```
class gameEngine
{
public:
  gameEngine();
  ~gameEngine();


// the stack of states
  std::vector<gameState*> states;
...
};
```

Wich has a stack of gameState objects once it works.
Now my problem is, that I want the gameStates to have a pointer to the gameEngine, so that the states can manipulate it, change states and can access data that all the states need.

I thought I can just have a pointer in the states class and use the construcktor but is gives me an error.

|15|error: 'gameEngine' does not name a type|

This is my states class.

```
class gameState
{
public:
    gameState(gameEngine* e);
    ~gameState();

    gameEngine* engine;//Here is the error

};
```

Is my logic false and is it impossible or how can I realise it?

Edit:
I tried to put class gameEngine; before my gamestate class.
If I do this it gives me a bunch of other errors.
In the whole gameEngine class all gameStates are now undeclared sais the compiler.

|16|error: 'gameState' has not been declared|

Everywhere where I use gameState inside of the gameEngine class.

Edit2:
I have it working now.Cyber's answer with the forward declaration worked and I had a wrong order of #include at first. Thank you everybody.

Comment: I assume `gameEngine` is defined **after** `gameState`. So `gameState` has no idea what a `gameEngine` is. Use forward declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [does not name a type error in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c)

Comment: _"Wich has a stack of gameState objects once it works"_ no it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to forward declare your `gameEngine` class before using a pointer in your `gameState` class.

```
class gameEngine;  // <-- forward declaration
class gameState
{
public:
    gameState(gameEngine* e);
    ~gameState();

    gameEngine* engine;
};
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried that already.
If I do this it gives me a bunch of other errors.
In the whole gameEngine class all gameStates are now undeclared sais the compiler.

|16|error: 'gameState' has not been declared|

Everywhere where I use gameState inside of the gameEngine class.

Comment: Then post those errors too. Edit your original question with these errors and what you tried.