# 'GLEWContext does not name a type' error on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, glew

I am trying to port a glew_mx project from windows to ubuntu but I always get errors because of GLEWContext being undefined.

```
error: ‘GLEWContext’ does not name a type
```

I know that I dont really need GLEWContext on linux but nevertheless I have to define

```
GLEWContext* glewGetContext();
```

in order to compile my project. So I created a global GLEWContext and simply return it in glewGetContext. 
My window.h code looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#define GLEW_MX
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#define GLM_SWIZZLE
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/ext.hpp"

#ifdef _WIN32
#define CONTEXT_PREFIX  window
#else
#define CONTEXT_PREFIX 
#endif

namespace window
{
    class Window
    {
    public:   
        Window() {}
        ~Window() {}

        //...

#ifdef _WIN32
        static void makeContextCurrent(Window* window_handle);
#endif
        static Window* createWindow(int win_width, int win_height, const std::string& title, GLFWmonitor* monitor, Window* share);

        GLFWwindow* window;
#ifdef _WIN32
        GLEWContext* glew_context;
#endif
        //...

    private:
        //...
    };

    GLEWContext* glewGetContext();
#ifdef _WIN32
    //...
#else
    GLEWContext* glew_context;
#endif
}
```

And the code in window.cpp looks like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
GLEWContext* window::glewGetContext()
{
    //...
}
#else
GLEWContext* window::glewGetContext()
{
    return glew_context;
}
#endif
```

The error occurs while compiling the last two lines in window.h
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the compiler compiles the your `Window`class and gets to the `GLEWContext* glew_context` line. But `GLEWContext` may not be defined, so [*forward declaration*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/does-not-name-a-type-error) might be helpful.

Since you are porting from windows to ubuntu you have to be sure that the `#pragma` is supported by your compiler. You may change your include guard to

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H
// Your code here
#endif
```