# Does not name a type, C++ error?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

> **Error messages:** **Display::Display = Display does not name a type, Member declaration not found,Type 'std::string' could not be resolved,
>   add a breakpoint**
>
> **Display::~Display = Display does not name a type, Member declaration not found, add a breakpoint**

I've looked at other "does not name type" question on stack but most of them were due to misplacing, example: ["does not name a type" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/does-not-name-a-type-error)

I don't really think I misplaced anything considering it's only 1 header file but maybe I overlooked something? Any help would be appreciated

display.h

```
#ifdef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H

#include <string>

class Display{
          public:
                Display(int width, int hight, const std::string& title);
                virtual ~Display();
         protected:
         private:
                Display(const Display& other){}
                Display& operator = (const Display& other){}
       };
 #endif
```

display.cpp

```
#include "project\display.h"
#include <iostream>

Display::Display(int width, int hight, const std::string& title){}
Display::~Display(){}
```

Comment: please update the post and add the code instead of screenshots

Comment: that's all the code I have other than an empty main.cpp with a main function but I couldn't include that because I'm only limited to 2 links

Comment: @user7839375 They're saying that you should put the code in the question, not link to screenshots.

Comment: okay, i did it.

Comment: `Class` instead of `class`?

Comment: already got a solution though but thanks anyways

Comment: sorry it's the middle of the night guys lol. fixed it though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
#ifdef DISPLAY_H
// ...
#endif
```

with:

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H
// ...
#endif
```

Your compiler basically sees *Display.h* as an empty file, because `DISPLAY_H` is not defined, and `#ifdef` skips out the whole class declaration in the header file.